# jQuery each loop

Tags: jquery, loops, each

currently this is static code :

if you compare div ids no to that of a hrefs of second list  is getting added by +1

for example

slide0 » #pic1 to #pic5

slide1 » #pic2 to #pic6

and so on.. how should i achieve this with jquery each loop or any other jquery method ?
thanks in advance

```
<div id="my-slides">
    <div id="slide0">
        <ol>
            <li><img class="blank" src="images/thumbnails/blank.png" alt="" /></li>
            <li><a href="#pic1"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic1.jpg" alt="Winter branches" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic2"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic2.jpg" alt="Wading birds" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic3"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic3.jpg" alt="Bird on a post" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic4"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic4.jpg" alt="Early bloomers" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic5"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic5.jpg" alt="Green lizard" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#slide1" ><b>Next</b></a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div id="slide1">
        <ol>
            <li><a href="#slide0"><b>Previous</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic2"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic2.jpg" alt="Wading birds" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic3"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic3.jpg" alt="Bird on a post" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic4"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic4.jpg" alt="Early bloomers" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic5"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic5.jpg" alt="Green lizard" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic6"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic6.jpg" alt="Feeding the birds" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#slide1" ><b>Next</b></a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div id="slide2">
    <ol>
            <li><a href="#slide1"><b>Previous</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic7"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic7.jpg" alt="Feeding the birds" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic8"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic8.jpg" alt="A group of butterflies" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic9"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic9.jpg" alt="Ladybirds" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic10"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic10.jpg" alt="Butterfly" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pic11"><img src="images/thumbnails/pic11.jpg" alt="Trees in the mist" /></a></li>
            <li><img class="blank" src="images/thumbnails/downx.png" alt="" /></li>
    </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does "i want to generate href " pic(n)" attribute" mean?

Comment: for example <li><a href="#pic7"> here how shouuld i get this no 7 from jquery each loop function Thanks for your response

Comment: Update your question so it makes sense because I don't have a clue what you want to do, nor does anyone else right now. Stackoverflow isn't a guessing game.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('a[href^=#pic]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('href').match(/^#pic(\d+)/)[1]);
});
```

Comment: Yes! I am getting alert the way i want but still i cant able print my code any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I got what i want in last step i added like as follows 
 var beta = ($(this).attr('href').match(/^#pic(\d+)/)[1]);
$(this).attr('href', '#pic'+beta);
is this a right way thanks a lot

Comment: Hi but its dependent on href^=#pic is there any way to wright this  without href^=#pic please reply :-) waiting for your reply eagourly  eagerly

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ol li a:not(:first-child),ol li a:not(:last-child)").each(function()
{
    $(this).attr("href",<value>);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#my-slides a img').each(function() {
    var pic_number = $(this).parent().attr('href').substr(3);
    $(this).parent().parent().attr('href', pic_number);
}
```